# Find make dependency list based on files containing a special string

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have two targets in my makefile, `target-one` and `target-two`.
`target-one` builds on all source files listed in `TARGET_ONE_SRCS` as shown in below code segment.
But I wnat to build the `target-two` with dependencies are files from same list `TARGET_ONE_SRCS`,  but only those containing a special string.
for example `"#defile SPECIAL"` (build only with files containing `SPECIAL`).

How can I list the dependences for `target-two`? what is the correct approach?
I want `TARGET_TWO_SRCS` in fact.

```
TARGET_ONE_SRCS = file1.c file2.c file3.c file4.c file5.c
TARGET_ONE_OBJS = $(TARGET_ONE_SRCS:.c=.o)
target-one: $(TARGET_ONE_OBJS)
       $(CC)RULE...
target-two: .....
```

Thank you

Comment: `TARGET_TWO_SRCS = $(shell grep -l SPECIAL $(TARGET_ONE_SRCS))`?

Comment: I recommend using `:=` here rather than `=`.